How can I correct this to satisfy the Lint message in Flutter?
I am getting the following lint on
Text("The color is " + item['color'])

"Use interpolation to compose strings and values. (Documentation)  Try using string interpolation to build the composite string."
Here is how the code is used in my ListView / ListTile.  How could I re-write it better, there are no hints.
child: ListView.separated(
            itemCount: dataList.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              final item = dataList[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: item['value'] == ''
                    ? 
                    Text(
                            "The color is " + item['color'])
                       


Use string interpolation as suggested.

u can use
Text("The color is ${item['color']}")

instead of
Text("The color is " + item['color'])

